# How do you solve (manually) this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve (manually) for $a$:

$38 = \large \frac{(1+a)^{48} - 1}{a*(1+a)^{48}}$

Thanks!

Comment: This is equivalent to a degree $48$ polynomial equation. There is no general "formula" for solving this kind of equation. Various approximation techniques work well enough for practical purposes.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think you meant $49$.

Comment: Yes, am looking at tiny screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To work by calculator write it as $a=\frac 1{38} \left(1- \frac 1{(1+a)^{48}}\right)$.  Now you can iterate:  start by pretending $(1+a)^{48}$ is pretty big, so our first approximation is $a=\frac 1{38}\approx 0.026$, then plug that into the right and continue.  It doesn't converge very quickly.  [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20a=1/38%2a%281-1/%281%2ba%29%5E48%29) gives a numeric answer of about $0.00996937$, but it takes over $20$ iterations to get below $0.01$.  A spreadsheet makes it easy.

Comment: It always helps to start in the right place. I started a Newton-Raphson computation at $1/76$ (halfway between 0 and 1/38) and found $0.009969365412$ in just six iterations. But it's far from manual.

Comment: @PeterPhipps:  it later occurred to me that bisection would get there quickly, and that could be done manually.  As I was working with a spreadsheet and had copy down to do the iteration, this was the fastest route to a solution.